# Check datatable has row at selected index using loop

Tags: vb.net

Check if datatable has row at selected index using a for loop

i Want to check here if datatable has row at that value of 'i' which comes from loop

```
   Private Sub btnAct_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAct.Click


    Gross = 0
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing
    Act1 = dt.Rows(0)("Account")
    Act2 = dt.Rows(0)("Account")

    'Next
    For i = 0 To 100 Step 1
        If ( i Want to check here if datatable has row at that value of 'i' which comes from loop) Then

else

 If (Act1 = Act2) Then

        Else

            Act1 = dt.Rows(i - 1)("Account")

            For k As Integer = 0 To (i - 1) Step 1

                Act2 = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(k)("Account"))

                If (Act1 = Act2) Then

                    Gross += Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(k)("Total_Gross_Amount"))

                End If

            Next

            dr = dt.NewRow()

            dr("Account") = "Total"
            dr("Total_Gross_Amount") = Gross
            Gross = 0
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, i)
            Act2 = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(i + 1)("Account"))

        End If
        Act1 = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(i + 1)("Account"))

        dt(i)("Sno") = i + 1
    Next


        End If




    'Next

End Sub
```

I have a datatable And I want to check it has row at selected value which comes from a for loop

Comment: format your question for a better understand give some more description

Comment: i want to check datatable in for loop which has end's at 100 i want to check data table has row at that value if it does not have value at that index then it will check and comes out otherwise it will do it works

Comment: `if dt.rows(i).item("columnName") <> 0` or `if dt.rows(i).item("columnName") <> "`

Answer (score 2):

Simple - LINQ to the rescue:

```
For i = 0 To 100
  ' Functionally equivalent to
  ' dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().ElementAtOrDefault(i).
  Dim rowAtIndex = dt.AsEnumerable().ElementAtOrDefault(i)

  If rowAtIndex IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Do something with the row.
  End If
Next
```

Or a slightly less expressive, but better optimised version:

```
For i = 0 To 100
  Dim rowAtIndex As DataRow = Nothing

  If i < dt.Rows.Count Then
    rowAtIndex = dt.Rows(i)

    ' Do something with the row.
  Else
    ' Row at index does not exist.
  End If
Next
```

The big question here is though: *does `i` really need to go beyond* `dt.Rows.Count - 1` (which is the index of the last row in the `DataTable`)? If not, I'd rather change the loop to

```
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
```

Comment: actually first i was doing for i=0 to dt.rows.count-1 but there was problem at run time the number of rows in datatable are increasing but in loop it assume value which was at compile time before button click like datatable has 25 rows after button click in for loop rows are increasing to 35+ but the loop counts only up to    25 so it edits only 25 rows and remaining rows are same as it was . i did this task in c# by dt.rows.count-1 it was working their but i do not know what's the issue with vb.net . @Kirill Shlenskiy